# How to use search filter in Angular for nested JSON object?

Tags: node.js, json, angular, mongoose

I am bringing data from my mongoose to display on my HTML table. I am able to filter a JSON object normally but unable to filter nested JSON object?

I have used "`npm i ng2-search-filter --save` " to import filter pipe, but this only works for the first level. Doesn't do filter for the nested JSON object.

My JSON object is:

```
{
    packageName:test,
    packagePrice:200,
    userid:{
        userName:John,
        userAge: 27
    }
}
```

---

```
     <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="searchtext" 
     placeholder="Search">

      <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Package Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Package Price</th>
          <th scope="col">Customer Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Customer Age</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody *ngFor="let use of user | filter:searchtext">
        <tr class="table-active">
          <td> {{use.packageName}}</td>
          <td>{{use.packagePrice}}</td>
          <td>{{use.userid.userName}}</td>
          <td>{{use.userid.userAge}}</td>       
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

When I enter packageName and packagPrice in a textbox for search filter it filters out and shows me correct result, but on userName and userAge its not working.
Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Now this feature is available in the latest release of the [`ng-search-filter`](https://github.com/solodynamo/ng2-search-filter/releases/tag/0.4.9)

Comment: @PrashantPimpale tried pasting this in my node_module, didn't work

Comment: Which command did you use?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale previously i had installed using this command ng2-search-filter, and then later i just replaced the existing node_module file of ng2-search-filter with the rar file from  https://github.com/solodynamo/ng2-search-filter/releases/tag/0.4.9 this link

Comment: there's is an issue in the latesr release try now its now fixed

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I installed in npm i ng2-search-filter --save again, but its not working on nested JSON object. I can search packageName and packagePrice but not userName and userAge from above example.

Comment: See [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zrdwke-angular-search-pipe-uubbrk)

Comment: @PrashantPimpale it was my mistake, I was installing the wrong version of the package, that was creating the issue. I installed the latest one now it's working fine. Thanks alot :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this with by just installing the latest version [`ng2 search filter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-search-filter).

Run below command:

> npm i ng2-search-filter@0.5.1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `custom search pipe` for this

I have create demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zrdwke-angular-search-pipe?file=src/app/search.pipe.ts)

searchPipe.ts

```
transform(value: any, searchText?: any): any {
    if(!value) return [];
    if(!searchText) return value;
    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
    return value.filter( it => {
      return it.packageName.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) || it.packagePrice.toString().includes(searchText) || (it.userid &&  it.userid.userAge.toString().includes(searchText) || it.userid.userName.toLowerCase().includes(searchText));
    });
}
```

component.html

```
<tr class="table-active" *ngFor="let use of user | search:searchtext">
    <td> {{use.packageName}}</td>
    <td>{{use.packagePrice}}</td>
    <td>{{use.userid.userName}}</td>
    <td>{{use.userid.userAge}}</td>       
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:-

```
function getResult(filterBy, objList) {
return objList.hightlights.filter(function(obj) {
return obj.queries.some(function(item){
 return item.indexOf(filterBy) >= 0;
});
});
}
```

Comment: where should i paste this ?

Comment: you should edit as per your code this is one type of example you should edit please as per your requirement

Comment: @Shubham This will not work! He is using a third party library `ng2-search-filter`